# Update table column using join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

Can anyone help with this sql code, i'm trying to update the table column FirstURLForSite to 1 for the 1st match, but I'm struggling with the code, I'm only looking to update the 1st match.

Can anyone help, hopefully you can understand what i'm trying to do.

```
update [dbo].[at_WebsitesSearch]
set [FirstURLForSite] = 1
where(

left outer join
select min(ID) as rowid, [BaseURL]
from [dbo].[at_WebsitesSearch]
group by [BaseURL]) as FirstMatch on
[dbo].[at_WebsitesSearch].id = FirstMatch.rowid
where FirstMatch.rowid is null
```

Example of data

```
BasesURL                                FirstURLForSite
http://asia1x1.net/                         1
http://asia1x1.net/                         0
http://asia1x1.net/                         0

http://australia.bedandbreakfasts.net/      1
http://australia.bedandbreakfasts.net/      0
http://australia.bedandbreakfasts.net/      0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try, *I'm trying to fix your current query*.

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.FirstURLForSite = 1
FROM    at_WebsitesSearch a
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  MIN(ID) AS rowid, BaseURL
            FROM    at_WebsitesSearch
            GROUP   BY BaseURL
        ) FirstMatch
            ON FirstMatch.rowid = a.id
WHERE   FirstMatch.rowid IS NULL
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  BasesURL, FirstURLForSite,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BasesURL ORDER BY BasesURL ASC) rn
    FROM    at_WebsitesSearch
)
UPDATE  records
SET     FirstURLForSite = CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN rn ELSE 0 END
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3f775/1)

Answer (score 0):

> You have to do something like this. Also check them Fiddle Demo below.

```
;WITH CTE  
AS  
(  
    SELECT  BasesURL, FirstURLForSite,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BasesURL   
                            ORDER BY BasesURL DESC) RN  
    FROM    at_WebsitesSearch  
)  
UPDATE  CTE  
SET     FirstURLForSite = 1  
WHERE RN = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dedb4/1)